# TFS Build GetBuildDirectory and Store it

Tags: tfs, build-process

I'm trying to get a TFS current build directory path but it's not working. I've tried this:

Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Activities.Extensions.WellKnownEnvironmentVariables.BuildDirectory

I see it printing right path with "GetBuildDirectory" Step (in the diagnostics log), but How would I store this information into a variable?

[image]

ANSWER:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There have been **TF_BUILD environment variables**.You can use the TF_BUILD environment variables to get key bits of data that you need for your build process logic. More from MSDN: [Team Foundation Build environment variables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh850448(v=vs.120).aspx)

You could just reference the `TF_BUILD_BUILDDIRECTORY` to get The build agent working directory. For example: *C:\Build\BuildBot3\CoolApp\CIBuild.*

Comment: but how? when I do this: String.Format("11Build Directory: {0}", TF_BUILD_BUILDDIRECTORY), it throws an error

Comment: For powershell script. Usually use 'Write-Host "Drop Location is " `$Env: TF_BUILD_DROPLOCATION` or you can use this `xxx="$(TF_BUILD_BUILDDIRECTORY)" ` in MSBuild Arguments.  A example for you reference: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/visualstudio/1035/environment-variables-visual-studio-2013-tfs

Comment: Well, not at all .Turned out to be this reason.